# Setting a URL alias breaks the relative image paths on those pages. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: path-aliases

I set a URL alias for one of my content type pages. So now every 'newsroom' content type is at `http://myurl.com/newsroom/name-of-article`. That's perfect. But that page also has blocks that contain images and now the paths to those images are broken.

my block contains: `scr="sites/default/files/mobile-nav.png">` 
but the page is trying to find the image at `src="NEWSROOM/sites/default/files/mobile_nav.png"`

The block that contains the image is on every page of the site because it's the mobile nav.

How do I change my url alias? Or what do I need to do to tell drupal how to find the images correctly while keeping the image path relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src="sites/default/files/mobile-nav.png"> should be src="/sites/default/files/mobile-nav.png">

Please note the additional "/" before "sites." Without the forward slash the image will always be called from wherever you're at on the site so if you were at say site.com/news/ it would look for the images in site.com/news/sites/default.... if you don't have the forward slash before sites.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep your code independent from your base path, so that if later on your install path changes to a subdirectory or another domain, paths will still work. Try this:

```
<?php global $base_path; ?>
... src="<?php print $base_path; ?>sites/default/files/mobile-nav.png"
```

`$base_path` contains the path to the Drupal installation (at least a "/" - [see Drupal docs for details](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_path/7)). Notice that it must be declared as global before use.